# Remove or hide create new sites button in google for user?

Tags: google-apps, google-sites, google-groups

I have created sites and group in google. And i don't want to user can create new sites or new group. So how to restrict the option to users?

Comment: Are you using a Google consumer (gmail.com) account or a G-Suite account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think no, if you have an google account , you can create a google sites. I think it's just Google Group can be restricted to create a group.